# jQuery UI autocomplete positioning issues

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, positioning, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have seen some other posts similar to this but nothing that really answers this specific question. Trying to use the out-of-the-box jQuery UI autocomplete widget in a project.. It positions fine under my input(unlike other posts issues saying it starts at 0,0), however when I size the window up and down with the auto suggest results showing, the position doesn't follow the input box with the window size reflow. It stays at the position it was when it was called. If you type another letter into the input the results box will jump back under the input in the correct position, but it won't do this by the window size change events? TIA.

***JS Fiddle Example:*** http://jsfiddle.net/thomaswicker/m0L86d7m/

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$('input').autocomplete({
    search: function(event, ui) {
        $('section .test ul').empty();
    },
    source: ["something", "something-else"]
}).data('autocomplete')._renderItem = function(ul, item) {

    return $('<li/>')
   .data('item.autocomplete', item)
   .append(item.value)
   .appendTo($('section .test ul'));
};
```

HTML:

```
<section>
    <input id="autocomplete"/>
    <div class="test">Output goes here:<br/><ul></ul></div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
section {
   width: 400px;
   height: 100px;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   margin-top: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The margin set to auto is the problem. If you remove the two lines

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

it works. I think on a real page you don't really need those.

Comment: if you remove those it will put the div on left/left but in the real application the autocomplete box is positioned on the right of the screen so the issue does indeed cause a problem. I only have the margins on there to demonstrate the positioning isses

Comment: Unfortunately that won't work either, might work if I was building from scratch as a work around but this is in an enterprise application in which the search box already in a predefined area which I can't really hack around on. I need a solution that will work essentially if text align was set to center. The ta-right would work if the app wasn't responsive.

Comment: Another example I have seen of this same issue is at the URL below, although it doesn't appear he provided a solution either. It looks to be a positioning bug with jQuery UI in general but I have to find a work around. http://jsbin.com/orifoy/2

Comment: I was playing around a bit and tried this: http://jsfiddle.net/m0L86d7m/3/ But unfortunately, there's no way to re-open the box manually (like an `open` method)

Answer (score 0):

**You can add a window resize event listener and then call the [jQuery UI `.position()` method](https://api.jqueryui.com/position/).** You can see this being done in the [`suggest()` method in the source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/widgets/autocomplete.js#L530).

A good place to add this is in the [Autocomplete `create` event](https://api.jqueryui.com/1.10/autocomplete/#event-create), since this is called only once during widget creation.

It would look like this:

```
$('input').autocomplete({
    ...
    ...
    create: function(event, ui) {
        var widget = $(this).data('ui-autocomplete');
        var ul = widget.menu.element;           
        var positionProps = $.extend({ of: widget.element }, widget.options.position);

        // reposition autocomplete dropdown when window resizes
        $(window).on('resize', function() {
            ul.position(positionProps);
        });
    },
    ...
    ...
});
```

[Here's the working JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/7jmczo8L/)